# 100 percent load with multiprocessing queues

Tags: python

this only replicates my problem to get 100% load for the main python script if it tries to control loop over a shared queue

```
import multiprocessing
import random


def func1(num, q):
    while True:
        num = random.randint(1, 101)

        if q.empty():
            q.put(num)


def func2(num, q):
    while True:
        num = q.get()
        num = num ** 2
        if q.empty():
            q.put(num)


num = 2
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1, args=(num, q))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2, args=(num, q))
p1.daemon = True
p2.daemon = True
p1.start()
p2.start()
running = True
while running:
    if not q.empty():
        num = q.get(True, 0.1)
        print(num)
```

would there be a better method to control from a script multiple worker processes. Better in sense of no load !?

Comment: the while loops are producing the load. use time.sleep(x) in EVERY while loop to reduce the load. see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8077/how-can-i-lower-the-usage-of-cpu-for-this-python-program for more.

Comment: @KGM thanks for that. sleep es really recommended for processes with queues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your program:

- What's with the `num` parameter of `func1()` and `func2()`? It never gets used.
- `func2` will discard its result if `func1` happens to have posted another number after `func2` got the last number out of the queue.
- Why do you daemonize the workers? Are you quite sure this is what you want?
- The `if not q.empty(): q.get()` construct in the main code will sooner or later raise a `queue.Empty` exception because it's a race between it and the `q.get()` in `func2`.
- The uncaught `queue.Empty` exception will terminate the main process, leaving the two workers orphaned - and running.

General advice:

- Use different queues for issuing jobs (request queue) and collecting results (response queue). Include the request in the response if necessary.
- Think about how to terminate the workers. Consider a "poison pill", i.e. a value in the request queue that causes workers to die, i.e. exit/terminate.
- Be really really sure you understand the race conditions in your code, like the one I mentioned above (empty vs. get).

Here's some sample code I hacked up:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
import os

def request_generator(requests):
    while True:
        requests.put(random.randint(1, 101))
        time.sleep(0.01)

def worker(requests, responses):
    worker_id = os.getpid()
    while True:
        request = requests.get()
        response = request ** 2
        responses.put((request, response, worker_id))

def main():
    requests = multiprocessing.Queue()
    responses = multiprocessing.Queue()
    gen = multiprocessing.Process(target=request_generator, args=(requests,))
    w1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(requests, responses))
    w2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(requests, responses))
    gen.start()
    w1.start()
    w2.start()
    while True:
        req, resp, worker_id = responses.get()
        print("worker {}: {} => {}".format(worker_id, req, resp))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: this is of course just a reduced example code with unused fragments. I will work around the raise conditions you mentioned. Also separating queues makes sense. However I the question is still why 100 percent load is caused by the main while loop !?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the 100% load on my Debian Stretch b/c I consistently run into the race condition after a few seconds. My best guess would be that in the main process, in the `while True`, `if not q.empty()` is almost always `False`, so it's just a fancy way to say `while True: pass`, which chews up your CPU. That's just a guess, mind you. `q.empty()` is rather expensive, too. Try to design your code as to use it sparingly. But before going after performance issues, I'ld recommend going after strict correctness first.

Comment: oh ok, Thanks, I was able to reproduce it on alsmost nay os including ubuntu 18.04..I'll correct the code for now

Comment: your code example was missing import random however it worked like charm. Thanks a lot. Is time sleep really recommended for processes with queues ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, import fixed. `time.sleep()` is just my example safeguard against flooding the queue too much, because generating random numbers is quite fast :-) Where will your requests be coming from? Will you be needing some kind of denial-of-service protection?

Comment: I try to work are around an openCV process. E.g. for a webinterface, one for services compressing and sending recordings. The queues are used to control the recording, streaming activity. Also one queue for streaming to the webinterface. Idling unused and wake up the used ones is important as everything should run on a pi.

Comment: So the requests queue is filled by the web interface. There's enough delay in that :-) As for the workers, I'm no expert on  OpenCV, but haven't they got built-in multi-core support?